# Finding the generating function of a series with a binomial coefficient and a exponential coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

So I am given this series

$$2^8, 2^7 \binom{8}{1}, 2^6 \binom{8}{2}, 2^5 \binom{8}{3}, 2^4 \binom{8}{4}, 2^3 \binom{8}{5}, 2^2 \binom{8}{6}, 2^1 \binom{8}{7}, \binom{8}{8}, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...$$

which I converted to the summation

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2^8 \cdot \binom{8}{n} \cdot x^n)}{2^n}  $$

The problem is to find the closed form generating function for this series

I know that the closed form generating function for 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{8}{n}x^n = (1+x)^8$$ and 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2^8 \cdot x^n)}{2^n} = \frac{2^8}{1-x/2}$$

I just can't find anything in my book or online on how to deal with the combination of the two

Comment: You can do the binomial expansion of $(1+x)^8$.  What about $(k+x)^8$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^8\binom 8n x^n}{2^n}=\sum_{n=0}^8\binom 8n 2^{8-n}x^n
=(2+x)^8\qquad \blacksquare$$

---

*OR*

$$(a+x)^N=a^N\left(1+\frac xa\right)^N\\
=a^N\sum_{n=0}^N \binom Nn \left(\frac xa\right)^n\\
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^N\binom Nn \left(\frac xa\right)^n$$

Put $a=2,  N=8$:
$$(2+x)^8=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^8\binom 8n \left(\frac x2\right)^n\qquad \blacksquare$$

---

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

$$ \sum \frac{2^8 \binom{8}{n} x^n}{2^n} = \sum 2^8 \binom{8}{n} \left(\frac x2\right)^n = \cdots  $$

Comment: I think it's either $$\frac{2^8 * (1+x)^8}{1-x/2}$$ or $$2^8(1+x/2)^8$$ ( i don't really think it's the second one)
$$$$


My book and what I've found online hasn't given me enough information to choose which is right. Does multiplying the closed forms of sums like I did in the first one work?

Comment: @vicg, To multiply polynomials, you don't multiply their coefficients (since of course $(1+2x)(3+4x)$ is not $3+8x$). So you can't just multiply the functions together in order to get your function. (You CAN multiply generating functions, which is useful, but it doesn't give you the product of the coefficients, see Cauchy Product.)